# is it ok to leave R error (Cannot resolve symbol 'R') behind in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I googled why I am getting this error, `cannot resolve symbol 'R'`, and found 3 ways to solve it:

- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Sync Gradle
- update SDK

I already tried them, but it still doesn't solve the error except the invalidate one, **but** the errors come back when I open the java code file. So the invalidate option is a success if I don't check the java code after it.

Is it okay if I just leave it unsolved, if no error occurs, or are there any other ways to solve it?

Comment: Try putting manually in import <package name>.R
Eg: `import christal.ruby.project.R`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 1):

Usually cleaning and rebuilding the project solves the issue.